# Find a tapped childNode inside the node in 3D object in SceneKit in ARKIT

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I want to find a tapped childNode inside the node in 3D object in SceneKit. Like apple 3D object example of Cup node have child nodes as spoon , plate.  Once we touch spoon, how we can able to find that spoon got touched or plate got touched ???

Answer (score 4):

I keep an array in the ARViewController with the SCNNodes I want to react to tap. Then I perform a hitTest and check to see if the results contain that node. Something like this (I actually perform hit tests in a circle of radius R around tapped point too if hitTest fails to improve usability if tap was close enough to the object)

```
@objc func onTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let position = sender.location(in: scnView)
    let hitTestOptions: [SCNHitTestOption : Any] = [.boundingBoxOnly: false, .searchMode: SCNHitTestSearchMode.all.rawValue]
    var hitTestResults: [SCNHitTestResult] = scnView.hitTest(point, options: hitTestOptions)
    let filteredResults = hitTestResults.filter { (hitTestResult) -> Bool in
        return nodeBelongsToVirtualObject(hitTestResult.node)
    }
    let nearestNode = filteredResults.first?.node // This was the tapped node
}

private func nodeBelongsToVirtualObject(_ node: SCNNode?) -> Bool {
    if let _ = node {
        return self.nodes.contains(node!) || nodeBelongsToVirtualObject(node!.parent)
    }

    return false
}
```

So you'd need to keep track in the `nodes` array of those children nodes you want to detect tap on

Comment: Actually i already got the answer now .. it is vey simple .                             
let lastNode = sceneHitTestResult.last?.node

Answer (score 1):

name the nodes which you add to the sceneview with 
  yournode.name = "some name "

add tap gesture recognizer to the scene view and add the following code to the tapaction function

```
@objc func tapFunction(withGestureRecognizer recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer){

    guard recognizer.state == .ended else{return}
     let taplocation = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)
    let hittestreults = sceneView.hitTest(swipelocation,options: [:])
    guard let hitTestResult = hittestreults.first else { return }
    let finalnode = hitTestResult.node
     print(finalnode.name)}
```

check finalnode.name to know which node is tapped .